# Getting "Field 'dwell time' is not a java.lang.Number" error when retrieving data from Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, weka

I'm working on an Android project that uses Firebase Firestore to store data. I'm trying to retrieve a document from the Firestore database and get the value of a field called "dwell time" which is a number, but I keep getting the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Field 'dwell time' is not a java.lang.Number

I'm using the getLong() method to retrieve the value of the field, but it seems like the field is not being recognized as a number. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
package com.example.projetm.data;

import static java.sql.DriverManager.println;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import weka.core.converters.CSVSaver;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.DenseInstance;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instances;

public class Getdata  {

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private String PREFS = "KEYSTROCKES";
    private int nombre_instance; // hada nombre de tests
    private int nombre_attribute = 29; // hada nombre de collones
    public ArrayList  dwell = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList flightm2 = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList flightm3 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList name = new ArrayList<String>();
    int y=0;


    public String Class(Context context) throws Exception {

        //hna nkharej ga3 les utilisateurs
        db.collection("users").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    int nbruser = task.getResult().size(); //hna nedi nombre des utilisateurs
                    Log.d("nombre",String.valueOf(nbruser));
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) { //apres nboucle les utilisateurs

                        String id = doc.getId(); // nedi id ta3ah
                        //apres nedi dynamique regle de chaque utilisateurs
                        db.collection("users").document(id).collection("dynamic").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    y++; // w koul ma nedi test nzid f y
                                    Log.d("getdata1", String.valueOf(nombre_instance));
                                    nombre_instance+=task.getResult().size(); //w nmed l nombre instance le nombre de test


                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) { //apres nboucle les tests
                                        Log.d("data type", document.get("dwell time").getClass().getSimpleName());
                                        dwell.add(document.getLong("dwell time")); //nedi swalhah

                                        flightm2.add(document.getLong("flight time 2"));
                                        flightm3.add(document.getLong("flight time 3"));
                                        name.add(document.getString("nom"));
                                        Log.d("getdata1", "y = " + y);
                                    }
                                        if (y==nbruser){ //apres ki y yweli 9ad le nombre des utilisateurs sema da ga3  les tests ydir la suite
                                            Log.d("getdata", "wsel");
                                            //hna apres ncreeo  data
                                            preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                            //nsamo les atributs


                                            final Attribute Attribute1 = new Attribute("dwelltime1");
                                            final Attribute Attribute2 = new Attribute("dwelltime2");
                                            final Attribute Attribute3 = new Attribute("dwelltime3");
                                            final Attribute Attribute4 = new Attribute("dwelltime4");
                                            final Attribute Attribute5 = new Attribute("dwelltime5");
                                            final Attribute Attribute6 = new Attribute("dwelltime6");
                                            final Attribute Attribute7 = new Attribute("dwelltime7");
                                            final Attribute Attribute8 = new Attribute("dwelltime8");
                                            final Attribute Attribute9 = new Attribute("dwelltime9");
                                            final Attribute Attribute10 = new Attribute("dwelltime10");
                                            final Attribute Attribute11 = new Attribute("flighttime2_1");
                                            final Attribute Attribute12 = new Attribute("flighttime2_2");
                                            final Attribute Attribute13 = new Attribute("flighttime2_3");
                                            final Attribute Attribute14 = new Attribute("flighttime2_4");
                                            final Attribute Attribute15 = new Attribute("flighttime2_5");
                                            final Attribute Attribute16 = new Attribute("flighttime2_6");
                                            final Attribute Attribute17 = new Attribute("flighttime2_7");
                                            final Attribute Attribute18 = new Attribute("flighttime2_8");
                                            final Attribute Attribute19 = new Attribute("flighttime2_9");
                                            final Attribute Attribute20 = new Attribute("flighttime3_1");
                                            final Attribute Attribute21 = new Attribute("flighttime3_2");
                                            final Attribute Attribute22 = new Attribute("flighttime3_3");
                                            final Attribute Attribute23 = new Attribute("flighttime3_4");
                                            final Attribute Attribute24 = new Attribute("flighttime3_5");
                                            final Attribute Attribute25 = new Attribute("flighttime3_6");
                                            final Attribute Attribute26 = new Attribute("flighttime3_7");
                                            final Attribute Attribute27 = new Attribute("flighttime3_8");
                                            final Attribute Attribute28 = new Attribute("flighttime3_9");
                                            List<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>(){
                                                {
                                                    add("sahraoui");

                                                }
                                            };  //w ndir les classe

                                            //apres n ajoutou les attributs f fastvecteur
                                            Attribute AttributeClass = new Attribute("class",classes);
                                            FastVector fastVector = new FastVector(nombre_attribute);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute1);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute2);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute3);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute4);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute5);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute6);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute7);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute8);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute9);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute10);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute11);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute12);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute13);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute14);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute15);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute16);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute17);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute18);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute19);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute20);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute21);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute22);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute23);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute24);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute25);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute26);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute27);
                                            fastVector.addElement(Attribute28);
                                            fastVector.addElement(AttributeClass);
                                            //apres ncrreo instance avec nom dynamic w nmedo le nombre d'instance
                                            Instances instances = new Instances("dynamic",fastVector,nombre_instance);
                                            instances.setClassIndex(instances.numAttributes()-1);

                                            ArrayList finalDwell = dwell;
                                            ArrayList finalFlightm2 = flightm2;
                                            ArrayList finalFlightm3 = flightm3;

Log.d("taille", String.valueOf(finalDwell.size()));
                                            for (int i=0 ; i <nombre_instance;i++) { //apres nboucle pour chaque instance (test)
                                                int finalI = i; // i hiiya instance li rana fiha

                                                DenseInstance denseInstance = new DenseInstance(instances.numAttributes()) {
                                                    {

                                                        setValue(Attribute1, preferences.getInt("dwelltime1",(Integer) finalDwell.get(0)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute2, preferences.getLong("dwelltime2", (Long) finalDwell.get(1)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute3, preferences.getLong("dwelltime3", (Long) finalDwell.get(2)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute4, preferences.getLong("dwelltime4", (Long) finalDwell.get(3)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute5, preferences.getLong("dwelltime5", (Long) finalDwell.get(4)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute6, preferences.getLong("dwelltime6", (Long) finalDwell.get(5)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute7, preferences.getLong("dwelltime7", (Long) finalDwell.get(6)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute8, preferences.getLong("dwelltime8", (Long) finalDwell.get(7)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute9, preferences.getLong("dwelltime9", (Long) finalDwell.get(8)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute10, preferences.getLong("dwelltime10", (Long) finalDwell.get(9)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute11, preferences.getLong("flighttime2_1", (Long) finalFlightm2.get(0)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute12, preferences.getLong("flighttime2_2", (Long) finalFlightm2.get(1)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute13, preferences.getLong("flighttime2_3", (Long) finalFlightm2.get(2)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute14, preferences.getLong("flighttime2_4", (Long) finalFlightm2.get(3)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute15, preferences.getLong("flighttime2_5", (Long) finalFlightm2.get(4)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute16, preferences.getLong("flighttime2_6", (Long) finalFlightm2.get(5)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute17, preferences.getLong("flighttime2_7", (Long) finalFlightm2.get(6)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute18, preferences.getLong("flighttime2_8", (Long) finalFlightm2.get(7)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute19, preferences.getLong("flighttime2_9", (Long) finalFlightm2.get(8)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute20, preferences.getLong("flighttime3_1", (Long) finalFlightm3.get(0)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute21, preferences.getLong("flighttime3_2", (Long) finalFlightm3.get(1)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute22, preferences.getLong("flighttime3_3", (Long) finalFlightm3.get(2)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute23, preferences.getLong("flighttime3_4", (Long) finalFlightm3.get(3)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute24, preferences.getLong("flighttime3_5", (Long) finalFlightm3.get(4)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute25, preferences.getLong("flighttime3_6", (Long) finalFlightm3.get(5)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute26, preferences.getLong("flighttime3_7", (Long) finalFlightm3.get(6)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute27, preferences.getLong("flighttime3_8", (Long) finalFlightm3.get(7)));
                                                        setValue(Attribute28, preferences.getLong("flighttime3_9", (Long) finalFlightm3.get(8)));

                                                    }
                                                };


                                                instances.add(denseInstance); //apres n ajouter les donnes f instance
                                            }


// Create a file to save the CSV data to


                                            File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "data.arff");
                                            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
                                                // Save the CSV data to the file

                                                // create ArffSaver object
                                                ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
                                                // set the instances object to be saved
                                                saver.setInstances(instances);
                                                // set the file to save the instances
                                                saver.setFile(file);
                                                // save the instances to the ARFF file
                                                saver.writeBatch();
                                                Log.d("APP_TAG", "ARFF file saved at: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                            }

                                            Log.d("getdata", instances.toString()); // w n affichi les donnees f log


                                        }


                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return "fdg";


    }

}
```

[and this a screenshot of my Firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb88D.png)

I have verified that the 'dwell time' field is indeed a number field in Firestore, so I am not sure why I am getting this error. What could be causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why do you say that the `dwell time` field is a number while in the database is an array of numbers? What exactly would you like to query? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

> I have verified that the 'dwell time' field is indeed a number field
> in Firestore, so I am not sure why I am getting this error. What could
> be causing this error and how to fix it?

But the screenshot of your database shows 'dwell time' field is an array not a number, Just check if you set the 'dwell time' field right.